# How to select a specific text range of records in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column which contains data like P01,p02,p03 ect.
i need to retrieve specific records from p02 to p05. 
how to write query in sql server?

Actually Coloumn header is Project and its values are

```
Project id      Name    Work
    p01     nkjhas  driver
    p02     kjh     kjh
    p03     kjhkj   dfg
    etc
```

i need to get records from p02 to p05.

Comment: This is a very basic query.  What have you tried?

Comment: Actually Coloumn header is Project and its values are                        p01 nakjhas driver
p02 kjh kjh
p03 kjhkj dfg
etc i need to get records from p02 to p05..

Answer (score 3):

Your query looks something like:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.projectid >= 'p02' and t.project < 'p06';
```

You could also use:

```
where t.projectid between 'p02' and 'p05'
```

The first form is better if the project ids can be longer than 3 characters.